# How to get Primary and foreign Key details from MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need a query or C# code to get the primary key or foreign key details of each table in an MS Access database.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
   1. SELECT * FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A 
      JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C ON A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
      WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = <your table> AND C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
   2.  SELECT * FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A 
       JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C  ON A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
       WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = <your table> AND C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
```

1st is for primary key & 2nd one is for foreign key..........I think this may help you.

Comment: when putting code in an answer, it helps if the code is formatted as code. You do this by selecting the code and then pressing the {} button. I have put in a suggested edit to your response to format it appropriately.

Comment: Where are the tables `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` and `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` stored in an Access/Jet/ACE database? Seems to me this answer doesn't have any applicability to Access/Jet/ACE at all, but then I may not know some of the secrets of Access.

Comment: This answer patently does not apply to Access -- downvoting for posting useless answers that reflect an apparent lack of reading comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Try [OleDBConnection.GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135981.aspx)

Additional information : [Retrieving Database Schema Information (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx)

Comment: could you suggest a query to fetch the foreign and primary key of a each table(MS Access DB).By using GetSchema, I'm getting the information of the datasource.